# CodeIgniter - removed index.php AND .php extension using a .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Before I get slapped with a "Duplicate Question," please note that I am inquiring as to how I can add on some mod_rewrite rules to my current .htaccess with the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

My issue is, I have files outside of the application directory that are not set up with a Controller. So, how can I flat-out remove all .php extensions with my current .htaccess, WHILST retaining the ability to remove the index.php (or, index) parameter from the URL?

EDIT: I have tried another RewriteCond and RewriteRule. CodeIgniter throws a 404, though, since it thinks it is a Controller.

Comment: Have you tried adding a second `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` after the CodeIgniter rules? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4026967/2191572. If you already tried this then update your question with your results and how it failed for you or else get slapped with "Duplicate Question".

Comment: Apologies - see updated question.

Comment: Have you tried putting the rule before the CodeIgniter rules?

Comment: The hell. That worked. Can you please put that into an answer so I can mark it as solved and upvote you? :)

Comment: Sure thing, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to **[Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess/4026967#4026967)** you should add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

to your `.htaccess` **BUT** you should add it before the CodeIgniter rules like so:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

# Serve up non-CodeIgniter PHP files if they are requested without their extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

# CodeIgniter rewrite rules
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Since `mod_rewrite` processes and applies rules in order, you want non-CodeIgniter files to be tried first and then fall into the CodeIgniter rules.

---

I have no affiliation with this site and I am sure there are others like it but if you ever wanted to just test rewrite rules with various URLs then check out https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: I want to know what is my problem?

Answer (score -1):

for removing index.php from URL in CodeIgniter. you must follow these steps.

1 . add the following code in .htaccess and .htaccess must be in the root folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

2 . change `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = '';`

you don't need to remove .php in CodeIgniter because that not exist.
if you want to learn! so use this code to remove `.php` extension
add this code to `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```